# Firewall configuration for remote connection

Tags: r, shiny

I want a Shiny Web App for sharing with some co-workers, but i do not have permission for using Virtual-Box or Docker, and therefore neither to use:

- Shiny Open Source Server.
- Nor Shinyproxy.

So the solution which I was considering was to expose an app to:

- A specific IPv4 Address.
- And Port.

To my Company's Domain Network (by-passing the Company's Proxy).

The solution actually works if:

- I Switch-Off the Computer's Domain Firewall ("Windows Firewall > Turn
  Windows Firewall on or off").
- And in "Internet Options > Connection > LAN Settings > Advanced >
  Exceptions", set my IP Address Exceptions to By-Pass the Proxy.

  runApp(
      shiny_app_folder_address,
      launch.browser = TRUE,
      port = 8000,
      host = "192.168.215.25"
  )

The problem is that when I enable the Firewall again for my Domain, and in "Windows Firewall > Advanced Settings" set up an exception for an incoming port on the computer which runs the Shiny Web App, I cannot longer connect to the Shiny Web App from a Remote Computer.

Any suggestions?

Thank you.